# Github switch branches without committing local changes

Tags: git, github-desktop

I have been using an older version of Github desktop for Mac where I can switch branches without losing any local changes and without needing them to be stashed or temporarily committed.

[GitHub Desktop for Mac - Version 223](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp2vt.png)

But the Desktop 1.0 does not allow to have any uncommitted changes while switching branches. Is there any option to achieve the same old functionality?

Other answers seem to have one common suggestion: `git stash` and later `git stash pop`

My requirement is more trivial, just to achieve same functionality what I could do with the older desktop version.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is still not possible, even though it is requested in [`github.com/desktop/desktop` issue 1633](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1633).

That issue [explains why](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1633#issuecomment-357516924):

> We didn't put "magic stashing" on our roadmap for 1.0 because of our focus on implementing the baseline for both macOS and Windows - and it wasn't implemented on Windows. We also didn't talk about the underlying implementation of "magic stashing" and the problems as we saw it.
>
> I went digging through the history to find the various ways the original "magic stashing" implementation has affected users. Here's a non-exhaustive list:
>
> - "Magic stashing didn't restore uncommitted changes after syncing"
> - "Magic stashing can fail to restore changes with no indication that they still exist"
> - "Magic stashing may delete ignored files"
> - "Magic stashing fails if untracked files conflict"
> - "Magic stashing information will be lost if a repository moves on disk"

So in the meantime, the workaround remains:

> commit everything with a commit summary of wip or something similar and then, when returning to the branch, simply undo the latest change

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/634063/26237848/12e4da28-3c77-11e7-8505-6d8f77055658.gif]